# Visual Basic Winform - Bad performance when targeting build to AnyCPU/x64

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm facing a performance issue when building my winform project (.Net 4.0, Visual Studio 2012) using AnyCPU or x64 platform (release mode). My screen has around 500 controls (this is an old screen, including ListBox, Label, Panel, TextBox - just basic controls).

In AnyCPU/x64 build, it takes 90 seconds to initialize all the controls (I put timer before and after InitializeComponent method in designer file; no event is fired during control initialization time). In x86 build, it only takes 2-3 seconds to initialize all the controls.

All the 2 builds are in release mode. In debug mode, the performance is very good for both cases (2-3 seconds). My OS is Windows 7 64bit.

I used VMMap to see the memory graph of the 2 builds. Looking at the graphs (at the bottom of this question), I got the result below

**x86**

- Total (size): 356,172K
- Heap: 17,216K
- Managed Heap: 34,240K
- Stack: 17,920K
- Private Data: 21,232K
- Page Table: empty
- Free: 1,740,916

**x64**

- Total (size): 841,200K
- Heap: 49,284
- Managed Heap: 397,632
- Stack: 61,440K
- Private Data: 23,000K
- Page Table: 952K
- Free: 8,589,094,280K

There is no significant difference in Image, Mapped File, Shareable, Unusable.

I'm a little surprised that the Managed Heap of x64 is very large in comparison to x86's. Also, when the form is loaded, the private data of x64 is up to 1GB, then down to MBs; whereas, no significant change in x86.

Could you please help to explain me what could cause the difference in performance and data size? If you need more information, please let me know.

Many Thanks

[image]

Comment: Profile the lading phase. Or, pause the debugger 10 times to see where it stops most often. What's your app doing?

Comment: Thanks, but the issue does not occur in Debug mode. It only occurs in release mode and x64 target CPU. My app is an application about medical. It was migrated from VB6 to VB.NET and contains Japanese characters.

Comment: Start it in Release mode without debugger, then attach the dbeugger later. Or, use a profiler.

Comment: I tried to debug the app, but I cannot since no pdb files exist in output folder. Then I updated the build configuration to generate pdb files and magically the performance issue has gone. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this question by myself. Just apply the below configuration for the project in release mode will resolve the issue.

- Uncheck "Enable optimizations"
- Select "pdb-only" for General debug info

[image]

My project is converted from VB6 to VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008 so the build configuration is not the default value. I created a new VB.NET project and copy its configuration.

I'm not sure why these options affects the performance. This may be an issue of MS Build or there is another story behind the scene, I'm not sure. However, it works :-)